# Unresolved reference when referencing Java code from Kotlin tests in Spring Boot project using Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I have a project where I am using both Kotlin and Java code. My main Kotlin code (including the @SpringBootApplication main class) are in src/main/kotlin, but there is some legacy client library code which is in src/main/java.  I also have some tests in src/test/kotlin.

In IntelliJ I can run the tests without issue, but when I run the test using gradle test I get errors `Unresolved reference` and `cannot access class **`. I am unsure why this is happening. The errors related to code in the Java classes.

My kotlin code and tests are in a slightly different package to the client library code; my main code is in a package called com.sky.vision.playlistapi and the client library is in a package called com.sky.nifty. I wonder if this could be the root of the problem?

My build.gradle file is here:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.10'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version'1.2.10'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen' version '1.2.10'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.2.10'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa' version '1.2.10'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg' version '1.2.10'
}

group = 'com.sky.vision'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter')
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

    compile(group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8', version: kotlinVersion)
    compile(group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect', version: kotlinVersion)
    compile(group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4')
    compile(group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core')
    compile(group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind')
    compile(group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.9')
    compile(group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver')

    compile(group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.1.7')

    testCompile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile(group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-test')
    testCompile(group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-test-junit')

    runtime(group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.4-1201-jdbc41')
}
```

And here is my project layout:

[image]

If anyone is able to help me understand the problem I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I had some `.java` classes inside `src/main/kotlin` package. Once I moved these under `src/main/java` package the problem was resolved.